# Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs

Tags: matlab, vector

Could you help me, I have this error and I want to solve it, how can I do it? says something about vectorizing but I don't understand what part or what I'm doing wrong

Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output

the error occurs when solu4 and solu 5 have an empty or null value because there is no data on it and the 'matrix' collects all the data, but if I delete the code that says solu4 = [], like the Another problem is solved, but I need it to be there for me to have another error, what solution do they give me?
    cla;
    syms x y real ;

```
if isempty(get(handles.edit4,'String'))
    disp('4 5');
    solu4=[];
    solu5=[];
else
    solu4=double(vpa(struct2cell(solve([eqn1,eqn4],[x,y],'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))));
    solu5=double(vpa(struct2cell(solve([eqn2,eqn4],[x,y],'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))));
end

matriz=double([solu1'; solu2'; solu3'; solu4'; solu5']);
matrizx=matriz(1:end,1);
matrizy=matriz(1:end,2);

datmax=([min(matrizx),max(matrizx)]);
```